# Missing View Controller for Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I get the following exception:

> 'Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "PincodeView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

The issue seems that i use a View and not the View Controller like in the picture below, the problem is that i just dont have the option since it is not displayed there. Any idea what could be the issue that i dont have the option to create a View Controller?

How it should look like:

[image: View Controller]

Source: [Loading a .xib using MvvmCross and Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052836/loading-a-xib-using-mvvmcross-and-xamarin)

**Update:**

[image: What i could use]

**Update2:**

> Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017  Version 15.9.4
>   VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.4+28307.222 Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 4.7.03056
>
> Installed Version: Enterprise
>
> Visual C++ 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA722 Microsoft Visual C++ 2017
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   8.14.11009.1
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.9.04012.0 ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017
>
> ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   15.8.31590 Provides languages
>   services for ASP.NET Core Razor.
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.60913.0 For additional
>   information, visit https://www.asp.net/
>
> Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.9.03024.0 Azure App Service Tools
>   v3.0.0
>
> Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   15.9.02046.0 Azure Functions and
>   Web Jobs Tools
>
> C# Tools
>   2.10.0-beta2-63501-03+b9fb1610c87cccc8ceb74a770dba261a58e39c4a C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
>   settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.10 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> Extensibility Message Bus   1.1.49 (remotes/origin/d15-8@ee674f3)
>   Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled
>   Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.
>
> JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> JavaScript UWP Project System   2.0 JavaScript UWP Project System
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9 Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2017 - v2.9.10730.2
>
> Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
>   Simplifying the configuration of Azure DevOps pipelines from within
>   the Visual Studio IDE.
>
> Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting the
>   Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
>
> Microsoft Library Manager   1.0 Install client-side libraries easily
>   to any web project
>
> Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting
>   Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0 Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1 Develop, run,
>   validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5
>   your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL +
>   F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0 Microsoft Visual Studio VC
>   Package
>
> MLGen Package Extension   1.0 MLGen Package Visual Studio Extension
>   Detailed Info
>
> Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   4.13.12-pre (9bc9548) Support for
>   debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.
>
> NuGet Package Manager   4.6.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0 ProjectServicesPackage Visual
>   Studio Extension Detailed Info
>
> ResourcePackage Extension   1.0 ResourcePackage Visual Studio
>   Extension Detailed Info
>
> ResourcePackage Extension   1.0 ResourcePackage Visual Studio
>   Extension Detailed Info
>
> Sandcastle Help File Builder   SHFB Visual Studio integration for the
>   Sandcastle Help File Builder. https://GitHub.com/EWSoftware/SHFB
>
> Snapshot Debugging Extension   1.0 Snapshot Debugging Visual Studio
>   Extension Detailed Info
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61810.11040 Microsoft SQL Server Data
>   Tools
>
> TypeScript Tools   15.9.20918.2001 TypeScript Tools for Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>
> Visual Basic Tools
>   2.10.0-beta2-63501-03+b9fb1610c87cccc8ceb74a770dba261a58e39c4a Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
>   settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Visual F# Tools 10.2 for F# 4.5   15.8.0.0.  Commit Hash:
>   6e26c5bacc8c4201e962f5bdde0a177f82f88691. Microsoft Visual F# Tools
>   10.2 for F# 4.5
>
> Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0 Interop layer for
>   hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0 Visual Studio Tools for
>   Containers
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.28307.208 The
>   Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a
>   single universal app experience that can reach every device running
>   Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft
>   Windows 10 Software Development Kit.
>
> VisualStudio.Mac   1.0 Mac Extension for Visual Studio
>
> Xamarin   4.12.3.77 (d15-9@e3f40b477) Visual Studio extension to
>   enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin Designer   4.16.13 (45a16efd4) Visual Studio extension to
>   enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.
>
> Xamarin Templates   1.1.128 (6f5ebb2) Templates for building iOS,
>   Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK   9.1.4.2 (HEAD/8255f42fc) Xamarin.Android
>   Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>
> Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   12.2.1.12 (65ec520) Xamarin.iOS and
>   Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Answer (score 1):

Well that is not a problem if you cannot see it here, you can simply search it in the **TOP-Left** search box and see if it is Available, Also note that there are a lot of templates that have been added to the `iOS(Apple)` section which has moved `ViewController` a little lower in the hierarchy and hence you might not have found it,

Also in case you still are not able to find it i would suggest you repair your visual studio and that should solve your issue.

Comment: I added my current view to my question, even with searching and repairing of visual studio, there is still no normal View Controller without the Storyboard.

Comment: Can you tell me your visual studio configuration?

Comment: You can always create the ViewController with storyboard and then just delete the storyboard.

Comment: @Cyriac Oh yeah you can do what the guy in the comment above is suggesting, How could i miss that lol

Comment: Taking the ViewController with storyboard, removing the storyboard and adding a xib results in the same error as before. Well iam using the newest version of Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. I updated my question with the details.

Comment: Even I have the latest vs2017 and it does not have the template, I would suggest you add a direct xib file and then link it with a viewcontroller

Comment: I tried linking afterwards, which resulted in the error displayed at the top. But i will see if i can find another way and update it here then.

Comment: Are you sure you did not miss anything while doing so? Can you show me what you did earlier when you created the ViewController?

Comment: Thanks for the input. My current workaround is to duplicate one of my old views and adjust it properly. This just does not seem to be a good solution. Other ways just did not work somehow and i have no idea why at this point.

Comment: What you can do is if you want to use that just downgrade to an earlier version of vs and use the template